# Array field name validation issue

Tags: laravel-5

I have fields with array field names and I am having issues validating the fields. An example is: user[first_name]

```
$this->validate(request(), [
    'user[first_name]' => 'required|min:15',
]);

if ($errors->any()) {
  print_r($errors->all());exit;
}
```

It seems that Laravel does not detect the field this way, I get 
`user[first_name]` is required.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to retrieve the `user` object from the request, e.g.:

```php
$this->validate(request('user'), [
    'first_name' => 'required|min:15',
]);
```

Or even better using dot notation:

```php
$this->validate(request(), [
    'user.first_name' => 'required|min:15',
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

replace user[first_name] with user.first_name

```
$this->validate(request(), [
    'user.first_name' => 'required|min:15',
]);
```